# Is it possible to mock a lambda expression?

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda

The first two functions `display_pane_1` and `template_1` are easily tested
in the method `test_1`. I want to refactor these two functions into a single function `display_pane_2`.

lambdademo.py:

```
def display_pane_1():
    display_register(template_1)


def template_1():
    return 'hello mum'


def display_pane_2():
    display_register(lambda: 'hello mum')


def display_register(template):
    print(template())
```

test_lambdademo.py

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import lambdademo


class TestLambda1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        p = mock.patch('lambdademo.display_register')
        self.mock_display_register = p.start()
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)

    def test_1(self):
        lambdademo.display_pane_1()
        self.mock_display_register.assert_called_with(lambdademo.template_1)

    def test_2(self):
        lambdademo.display_pane_2()
        self.mock_display_register.assert_called_with('????????')
```

Can you help me write a valid test for `display_pane_2`? I would like to test the complete lambda expression i.e. `lambda x: 'hell mum'` should fail.

I've tried two paths to a solution.

The first option is a simple copy of `test_1`,replacing the argument of `lambdademo.template_1` with a mock of `lambda`. I couldn't find anything in the manual that suggests how I should mock an expression like lambda.
If it is in the manual please tell me where.

My second option followed from a wider search here on Stack Overflow and out on the Internet. The lack of responsive hits for 'python expression unittest',
'python lambda unittest', 'python expression mock', or 'python lambda mock'
suggested that I may be asking the wrong question. Is my assumption that I will need to mock the lambda expression wrong?

I am aware that a simple coding solution would be to keep the original code but at this point I'm more interested in filling in a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: Why combine these functions in this way? If you want to be able to mock `template_1`'s functionality, it seems best to leave it exposed for mocking.

Comment: @user2357112. +1 for questioning the wisdom of using a lambda expression when it needs to be tested because it is also part of the A.P.I. for the code. My curiosity, however, was directed at the simpler question of how to test it if circumstances demand that it be used. It seems to me that any valid Python code should be testable and the programmer needs to know how to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the lambda expression is accessible somewhere like an attribute of a class or a module, then you could mock it, but that seems very unlikely. Usually, a lambda expression is used when you don't need a reference to the function. Otherwise, you'd just use a regular function.

However, you can retrieve the arguments to all calls on a mock object, so you could look at the lambda expression that was passed in. In an example like the one you gave, the simplest thing to do would just be to call the lambda expression and see what it returns.

```
from mock import patch

def foo(bar):
    return bar()

def baz():
    return 42

print foo(baz)

with patch('__main__.foo') as mock_foo:
    print foo(baz)
    print foo(lambda: 'six by nine')

    assert mock_foo.call_args_list[0][0][0]() == 42
    assert mock_foo.call_args_list[1][0][0]() == 'six by nine'
```

If for some reason you don't want to do that, then you could use the inspect module to look at the lambda expression. Here's an example that just dumps the source code lines where the function was defined:

```
from inspect import getsource
from mock import patch

def foo(bar):
    return bar()

def baz():
    return 42

print foo(baz)

with patch('__main__.foo') as mock_foo:
    print foo(baz)
    print foo(lambda: 'six by nine')
    print mock_foo.call_args_list
    for call_args in mock_foo.call_args_list:
        print '---'
        print getsource(call_args[0][0])
```

The results:

```
42
<MagicMock name='foo()' id='140595519812048'>
<MagicMock name='foo()' id='140595519812048'>
[call(<function baz at 0x7fdef208fc08>),
 call(<function <lambda> at 0x7fdef208fe60>)]
---
def baz():
    return 42

---
    print foo(lambda: 'six by nine')
```

Here is a version of your test that passes with your example code. It tests both ways: calling the template and inspecting the source of the template.

```
# test_lambdademo.py

from inspect import getsource
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import lambdademo


class TestLambda1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        p = mock.patch('lambdademo.display_register')
        self.mock_display_register = p.start()
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)

    def test_1(self):
        lambdademo.display_pane_1()
        self.mock_display_register.assert_called_with(lambdademo.template_1)

    def test_2(self):
        lambdademo.display_pane_2()
        template = self.mock_display_register.call_args[0][0]
        template_content = template()
        template_source = getsource(template)

        self.assertEqual('hello mum', template_content)
        self.assertIn('hello mum', template_source)
```

Comment: Your interesting and thoughtful answer moves the lambda expression from the code under test to the test. It appears that your function `foo` is acting as a shim between the lambda expression and the code where it is used. If I apply this shim pattern is to my original function `display_pane_2` I'd end up with three functions: `display_pane_2`, the shim, and the lambda expression. It suggests that a single function is indeed untestable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a shim, @lemi57ssss. I have updated my answer to include a test of your original example code.

Comment: I used the term 'shim' in its general sense of a spacer that is not required for the primary function of the components which it separates. It is there to support some secondary function, in this case, that of testing. The wikipedia entry for 'shim(computing)' suggests that this general use has morphed into a term which is not useful.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)
Your update was most illuminating.